# How to update numericInput default value based on DT row selected

Tags: r, shiny, numeric-input

I'd like to update the numericInput value based on the different row users select from a DT table.

Below is my simple example. So, if users select the 1st row, the value should be 50. If users select the 2nd row, the value should be 100. Is there a way to do it **without** using the 'refresh' button?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("price",
                        "Average price:",
                        min = 0,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 0),

            actionButton('btn', "Refresh")
        ),

        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput('out.tbl')
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    price_selected <- reactive({
        if (input$out.tbl_rows_selected == 1) { 
            price = 50
        } else {
            price = 100
        } 
    })

    observeEvent (input$btn, {
        shiny::updateNumericInput(session, "price",  value = price_selected())
    })

    output$out.tbl <- renderDataTable({
        Level1 <- c("Branded", "Non-branded")
        Level2 <- c("A", "B")
        df <- data.frame(Level1, Level2)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution using your reactive variable**

```
price_selected <- reactive({
    if (isTRUE(input$out.tbl_rows_selected == 1)) { 
        price = 50
    } else {
        price = 100
    } 
})

shiny::observe({
    shiny::updateNumericInput(session, "price",  value = price_selected())
})
```

Note that you can observe `input$out.tbl_rows_selected` directly  (you don't need the reactive variable)

Comment: Hi! In my real project, we can't rely on the number of row selected; instead, what we need is the actual value of the row. This is the actual flow:

1. Users select a row from DT
2. I create a binary variable for each row in my dataset based on the selected row. 
3. I'll calculate avg price of items with binary variable 1.
4. Use the value from #3 as the default value of numericInput.
5. Users can override the value if they choose too.
6. I'll use the value from #5 in other calculations.
Any suggestions on how to refresh the default value without using a button? Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you mean something like this:

    `shiny::observe({
        selected <- df[input$out.tbl_rows_selected,]
        
        shiny::updateNumericInput(session = session, inputId = "price", value = mean(selected$Price))
    })

    Level1 <- c("Branded", "Non-branded","Non-branded")
    Level2 <- c("A", "B","c")
    Price <- c(1,2,3)
    df <- data.frame(Level1, Level2,Price)
    
    output$out.tbl <- renderDataTable({
        df
    })`